# Server Authorization directory incorrect ownership during linux mint installation

Tags: directory, authorization, mdm

When installing linux mint 17.1 from a bootable usb onto a hard drive I get the following message:

'Server Authorization directory (daemon/servAuthDir) is set to /var/lib/mdm but is not owned by user 111 and group 121. Please correct the ownership or MDM configuration and restart MDM.'

I have used dd to write zeroes to the hard drive before doing this. The error occurs when I try to launch the live version from the usb in order to install it. After this error the following message appears: 'The computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining'. I'm not able to continue after this.

Using PartedMagic from a bootcd I am still able to boot. The Disk is 250GB in size, but gparted only detects 232 GB of that.

I hope there is someone who recognizes these errors and is able to suggest a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me tonight after using the Pendrivelinux Universal USB installer to create the bootable usb, however, my problem disappeared after I tried using the [rawrite](http://www.netbsd.org/~martin/rawrite32/) utility to write the mint CD image to my USB drive. (I suppose dd would work if you're creating the usb on a linux system)